# How can I disable javascript in firefox with selenium?

Tags: python

How can I add preferences to the browser so it launches without javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable Javascript when using Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285917/how-to-disable-javascript-when-using-selenium)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting firefox's profile to disable the javascript:

```
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

To check in the `webdriver` browser if javascript is enabled do the following:

On the menubar navigate to `Firefox > Preferences > Content` and the check button for `enable javascript` should be unchecked. Like the picture shown below.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. If you check `about:config` in your selenium driven Firefox instance, it still shows `javascript.enabled` `true`, and it executes javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable javascript directly from the browser. Steps:

- Type About:config in url
- Click I'll be careful, I promise
- Search for javascript.enabled
- Right click -> Toggle
- Value = false