# Disabling Javascript after page has been rendered in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Python. I've seen [How can I disable javascript in firefox with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655486/how-can-i-disable-javascript-in-firefox-with-selenium) which says to create a profile then load the driver with that profile. But I want to disable Javascript after a page has been rendered so this means I can't recreate the driver.

I've tried the following:

```
browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://wwwhatever.com')
browser.firefox_profile.set_preference('javascript.enabled', False)
browser.firefox_profile.update_preferences()
```

But I get this:

```
print browser.capabilities['javascriptEnabled']
True
```

Furthermore, the rest of my test still acts like Javascript is enabled.

Comment: Why do you want to disable Javascript after the page has been loaded? More specifically, do you need to disable JS overall or do you simply want to interact with the static page once it's loaded? And, since JS is concerned, when is the page loaded, i.e. are you taking into account scripts that might run to augment the page's appearance/contents as it loads, but would run after the rest has loaded?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with QuickJs extension - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjs/?src=search. This extension add Ctrl+q shortcut to disable javascript. Here is code:

```
profile = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension("addon-8753-latest.xpi") #QuickJs extension
browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get('http://wwwhatever.com')

#Turn of javascript, send Ctrl+q
body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.CONTROL + 'q')
```