# How to disable JavaScript in Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm using Capybara to fill in a form and download the results.

It's a bit slow when filling in the form, and I want to check if JavaScript is the culprit.

How do I turn off JavaScript?

The Ruby code was something similar to, but not the same as, the following (the following won't reproduce the error message, but it is somewhat slow).

```
require "capybara"

url = "http://www.hiv.lanl.gov/content/sequence/HIGHLIGHT/highlighter.html"
fasta_text = [">seq1", "gattaca" * 1000, ">seq2", "aattaca" * 1000].join("\n")

session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)

# Code similar to this was run several times    
session.visit(url)
session.fill_in('sample', :with => fasta_text)
session.click_on('Submit')
```

And the error I was getting (with my real code, but not the code I have above) was

> Warning: Unresponsive script
>
> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>   You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let
>   the script continue.
>
> Script: chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml:2884

I wasn't running Capybara as part of a test or as part of a spec.

To confirm that the code I wrote currently has JavaScript enabled (which is something I want to disable), doing

```
url = "http://www.isjavascriptenabled.com"
session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
session.visit(url)
```

indicates that JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: To clarify: you want to use Selenium to drive a real browser, but with JavaScript disabled? By default, Capybara uses a RackTest driver that does not execute JavaScript, but it also does not drive a real browser. Would that suit?

Comment: @TimMoore I'm not a web developer, but I assume a RackTest driver wouldn't work on a third party website (I don't run the hiv.lanl.gov site).

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct.

Comment: There's a related answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7492504/29470. The example there is for Java, but it should be translatable to Ruby/Capybara. I can try to write up a full answer when I have some more time, but maybe that will get you going.

Comment: Here's another helpful blog post with some Ruby code http://yizeng.me/2014/01/08/disable-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 1):

Capybara only uses JavaScript if you've specified a `javascript_browser`:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

And if you've specified `js: true` as metadata in your spec:

```
context "this is a test", js: true do
```

Check for both of those things. If they're not there and the test is *not* running in a browser or using Poltergeist, then it's probably not using JavaScript.

Comment: I've added more details to my question, including an almost-reproduction of the code. I wasn't running it in a spec. Also, even though I hadn't modified `javascript_driver=`, JavaScript seems to be enabled.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm right, here is an open issue to add an option to disable javascript when using poltergeist https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/489