# Selenium Firefox with Python3 FirefoxProfile.set_preference() ignored

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, python-3.4

I am trying to set different preference values on a selenium 2.53.1 driven Firefox 45.0.1 via Python 3.4. E.g. disabling javascript:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
>>> profile.set_preference('javascript.enabled', False)
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

However, this is ignored, `about:config` shows

```
javascript.enabled  true
```

and JavaScript code is executed normally. Although `about:config` does show that it is user set. What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't

> It can no longer be done globally from the User Interface. There are still a few other alternatives. Depending what you need to block it may be worth considering a script blocker  something such as

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/994809

Comment: OK, thanks for the reference. Actually, what is the preferred way to block 3rd party content (js or other content)?

Comment: BTW, how do I load driver = ```webdriver.Firefox()``` with an extension enabled? No add-ons are enabled by default.

Comment: For blocking part. please read the given url.  While for second.... will be under another question ;-)  Please look for "loading firefox profile in selenium".

Answer (score 0):

this is a rather old problem, but it is also easily fixed, at least in Selenium 3.14 and Firefox 63:

used Options() for disable JS:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.preferences.update({"javascript.enabled": False})
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.get('about:config')
```

And this quest was solved here):
[How to disable Javascript when using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285917/how-to-disable-javascript-when-using-selenium/53054654#53054654)