# How to disable load javascript in C# ChromeDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the Selenium ChromeDriver with C#. I want to disable javascript to increase the testing speed.
I have found a way to disable loading images, but I can't find how to disable javascript.

Update: I can disable js with the Firefox Driver using C#. The Question is how to disable javascript using the C# ChromeDriver specifically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Javascript when using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285917/how-to-disable-javascript-when-using-selenium)

Comment: That link is about Firefox setting. I want to set the chromedriver with C#.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting this question. It's a valid question and the documentation isn't clear how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Experimental Options this is how you do it in C#.

```
var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript", 2);

var driver = new ChromeDriver(outPutDirectory, chromeOptions.ToCapabilities());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tested with this code. But I got an error.
"invalid argument: entry 0 of 'firstMatch' is invalid
from invalid argument:cannot parse capability:goog:chromeoptions"

Comment: It might need chromeOptions.ToCapabilities() changed last line answer.

Comment: When create new ChromeDriver, constructor of chromedriver has no option about DesiredCapabilites.

Comment: I fixed errors based on your code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks if you could accept my answer that would be great.