# How to get text from element which is dynamic? (Disable/Enable Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have a html code which shows time.

```
<span class="inner-2pZN4z">09:37:24 (UTC-4)</span>
```

Now this will change every second to show the correct time (I think it uses javascript to update the time, because I don't see any class change.). Now I want to take the time in my python code. So, I executed:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='inner-2pZN4z']").text
```

This throws an exception:

> Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page
> document

**Edit**

I went through [How to disable Javascript when using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285917/how-to-disable-javascript-when-using-selenium) but disabling JavaScript for me will not work as there are other codes which need JavaScript.

**Question:** How can we disable/enable JavaScript in while executing python code using selenium chromedriver?

Comment: try with //span[contains(@class,'2pZN4z')], u can also try giving some wait before if page not loaded

Comment: @muraliselenium I think it uses javascript to update the time, because I don't see any class change. So contains will not solve I think

Comment: It seem that page updated by JS each second, so element becomes stale. You might need to disable JS on WD start or try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285917/how-to-disable-javascript-when-using-selenium/36782979#36782979) to disable it in runtime. P.S. Note that @class in code is not the same as in HTML

Comment: The class was just copy-paste error while adding question to SO, JavaScript cannot be disabled, edit made to the question for the same @JaSON

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps the class name is dynamic also. Can you search by part of class name (that starts with 'inner-' ? Of if you know the path to the parent go there then get child.

Comment: @KevinField I checked in console, class name doesn't changes. I tried `find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::")` then also same error. The issue is this error doesn't get triggered always at the same seconds, some time it will load til 30s some time 1s

Comment: try with javascript executor..

Comment: @muraliselenium sorry, I didn't get that... Could you please help me with an example?

Comment: try `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector(".inner-2pZN4z").textContent')`

Comment: @JaSON how can I use querySelector for: `find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::*[3]/div[2]").text` ?

Comment: Actually there is a way to use [XPath in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver)