# Get web elements as they shown through view source

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-inspector, view-source

Using this code below I get the `href` from a link element.

```
    Sting url
    List<WebElement> wElements = DriverFactory.getWebDriver().findElements(By.className("link-class"))
    if(wElements.size() > 0) {
        url = wElements[0].getAttribute("href")
    }
```

The problem is that it finds the element but not the `href` attribute!!!

If I use "Firefox Inspector" the element appears as `<span>` with the right class name but without `href` attribute.

```
<div><span class="link-class">The Title</span></div>
```

If I use the "View Page Source" the same element appears as an `<a>` tag, it has `href` attribute, but different class name!!!

```
<a href="/href/attribute/here" class="other-link-class"<span>The Title</span></a>
```

So, is there any way to get the `href` of an `<a>` element but as it shown in "View Page Source"? Using Java of course.

Comment: why you are looking for `link-class` when element `<a>` has `class="other-link-class"` ?

Comment: Because if I look for `other-link-class` doesn't find any element!!! The element has this class name only in page source view.

Comment: it means some javascript/lib dropping this element dynamically on page load

Comment: Is there any way to get it from page source view?

Comment: Try to disable JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285917/how-to-disable-javascript-when-using-selenium

Comment: I think the answer is in here https://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 1):

There can be some minor difference in the WebElements as shown through *View Source* and as shown through *Inspector* tool.

Both of the methods are two different browser features which allows users to look into the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of the webpage. The main difference is that, the *View Source* shows the HTML that was delivered from the AUT (*Application under Test*) to the browser. Where as, *Inspect element* is a *Developer Tool* e.g. [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) to look at the state of the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) after the browser has applied its error correction and after any Javascript have manipulated the DOM. In short, using *View Source* you will observe the *Javascript* but not the *HTML*. The HTML errors may get corrected in the *Inspect Elements* tool.

As using the *Firefox Inspector* you don't find the *`href`* attributes, similarly when you execute your tests as the `<span>` elements doesn't contains the *`href`* attributes and the value of the *`href`* attributes can't be collected.