# Selenium driver.page_source() extracts only partial HTML DOM

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, dom

I have a webpage that when I right click on it then view page source I get: `SECTION-A`

But when I click on it then Inspect I get much longer output, I tried to get the page source using JS but same problem and I'm getting the output in `SECTION-A`... How can I fix this?

Note: I'm looking for universal solution and not only for this specific website.

What I tried:

```
time.sleep(3)
html1 = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
html2 = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
html3 = driver.page_source()
```

I'm using chrome, is there any flag or solution for this problem?

---

`SECTION-A`:

```
<head><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var framePara = new Array(
0,
"main.htm",
1,
0,0 );
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var indexPara = new Array(
"192.168.0.1",
1742822853,
"tplinklogin.net",
0,0 );
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<title>TL-WR845N</title>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="wed, 26 Feb 1997 08:21:57 GMT">
<link href="../dynaform/css_main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="javascript" src="../dynaform/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
//--></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script language="javascript" src="../localiztion/char_set.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><script type="text/javascript">
var startUrl = "";
var startHelpUrl = "";
if(framePara[0] == 1)
{
    startUrl = "../userRpm/WzdStartRpm.htm";
    startHelpUrl = "../help/WzdStartHelpRpm.htm";
}
else
{
    startUrl = "../userRpm/StatusRpm.htm";
    /*changed by ZQQ, 2015.7.25, corresponding to function StatusRpmHtm*/
    if (framePara[2] == 0x08 || framePara[2] == 0x07 || framePara[2] == 0x06 || framePara[2] == 0x03)
    {
        startHelpUrl = "../help/StatusHelpRpm_AP.htm";
    }
    else if (framePara[2] == 0x04)
    {
        startHelpUrl = "../help/StatusHelpRpm_APC.htm";
    }
    else
    {
        startHelpUrl = "../help/StatusHelpRpm.htm";
    }
}
document.write("<FRAMESET rows=90,*>");
document.write("<FRAME name=topFrame marginWidth=0 marginHeight=0 src=\"../frames/top.htm\" noResize scrolling=no frameSpacing=0 frameBorder=0 id=\"topFrame\">");
document.write("<FRAMESET cols=182,55%,*>");
document.write("<FRAME name=bottomLeftFrame marginWidth=0 marginHeight=0 src=\"../userRpm/MenuRpm.htm\" noResize frameBorder=1 scrolling=auto style=\"overflow-x:hidden\" id=\"bottomLeftFrame\">");
document.write("<FRAME name=mainFrame marginWidth=0 marginHeight=0 src=" +startUrl+" frameBorder=1 id=\"mainFrame\">");
document.write("<FRAME name=helpFrame marginWidth=0 marginHeight=0 src="+startHelpUrl+" frameBorder=1 id=\"helpFrame\">");
document.write("</FRAMESET>");
</script></head>

        
    
<frameset rows="90,*"><frame name="topFrame" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="../frames/top.htm" noresize="" scrolling="no" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" id="topFrame"><frameset cols="182,55%,*"><frame name="bottomLeftFrame" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="../userRpm/MenuRpm.htm" noresize="" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" style="overflow-x:hidden" id="bottomLeftFrame"><frame name="mainFrame" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="../userRpm/StatusRpm.htm" frameborder="1" id="mainFrame"><frame name="helpFrame" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="../help/StatusHelpRpm.htm" frameborder="1" id="helpFrame"></frameset>

<noframes>
    <body id="t_noFrame">Please upgrade to a version 4 or higher browser so that you can use this setup tool.</body>
</noframes>


</frameset>
```

Comment: This too didn't work: `response = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.innerHTML;')`

Comment: That works but maybe you want outerHTML

Answer (score 1):

There can be substantial difference in the WebElements as shown through *View Source* and as shown through *Inspector* tool. Both the methods are two different browser features which allows us to look into the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). However the core difference between them is:

- *View Source* shows the HTML that was delivered from the AUT (*Application under Test*) to the browser.
- *Inspect element* is a *Developer Tool* e.g. [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) to look at the state of the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) after the browser has applied its error correction and after any Javascript have manipulated the DOM. In short, using *View Source* you will observe the *Javascript* but not the *HTML*. The HTML errors may get corrected in the *Inspect Elements* tool.

Hence you see a larger output using *Inspect*.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Get web elements as they shown through view source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699106/7429447)

---

### Solution

[page_source](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) is one of the most effective and proven approach using *Selenium* to extract the page source. However, there is a catch. You need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) of a ***static*** element within the webpage. As an example, to extract the *page_source* of the webpage **https://example.com** you can induce *WebDriverWait* for *`<h1>`* tag with innerText as *`Example Domain`* to be ***visible*** as follows:

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://example.com")     
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[text()='Example Domain']")))
  print(driver.page_source())
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but to answer my question How how I retrive the data as shown in Inspect Elements tool?

Comment: @Roi Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: where is that h3 element coming from, my page doesn't have one... Plus I'm looking for general solution to work with all websites.

Comment: @Roi I have added some more verbatim to the answer for more clarity and brevity. Let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: This still doesn't help, as I said it's not a matter of waiting time as I did time.sleep(1000) and same result, 2 I want general solution and yet you are suggesting a solution for very specific website.