# How to get the data from the elements tab in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-edgedriver

I'm scrapping a page in selenium (using the edge driver) and I've noticed discrepancies between the information under the elements tab in the dev window found here:

[image]

and the data returned from `browser.page_source()`, is there a way to get the data from the elements tab?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71763545/7429447) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71812637/7429447) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699106/7429447) discussion answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think some websites block or restrict the selenium user agent.

Change user agent:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

options.add_argument("user-agent=Something")

driver = webdriver ...
```

You can get random user-agent with `fake-useragent` module.

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

user_agent = UserAgent()
print(user_agent.random)
```

install:

```
pip install fake-useragent
```